# "Oh noes!" exception in Nancy testing

Tags: .net, exception, testing, nancy

The inner exception:

```
{"Unable to locate view 'home'\r\nCurrently available view engine extensions: cshtml,vbhtml,sshtml,html,htm\r\nLocations inspected: ,,,,,,,,views/Store/home-he-   IL,views/Store/home,Store/home-he-IL,Store/home,views/home-he-IL,views/home,home-he-IL,home\r\nRoot path: "}
```

The test code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void Spike()
    {
        // Given
        var foo = typeof (RazorViewEngine);
        var bar = typeof (SuperSimpleViewEngine);
        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

        // When
        var result = browser.Get("/mytest", with =>
        {
            with.HttpRequest();
        });

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

The Module looks like this:

```
public class YonatanModule : NancyModule
{
    public YonatanModule()
    {
        Get["/mytest"] = o =>
            {
                return View["home"];
            };
    }        
}
```

I've tried to add a reference to `Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor`, according to [this](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/making-my-first-nancyfx-test-pass.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245035/nancy-module-unit-testing-exception-in-unit-test).
I'm using Nancy 0.16.1, with Razor (Although I'm trying this first test with a clean html page).
Also, I'm using Azure, but in this case I do not run the emulator or anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10466315/219187

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by marking the view "Copy Always" in "Copy to Output Directory".
Not sure why it works in the web project but not via the `Browser` in the test project.

Comment: Because the views aren't copied to the test output location. Making them copy will force them to be copied to the bin directory allowing them to be run in your tests. The other way is to implement a RootPathProvider for use in unit tests.

Comment: Here's something I wrote on [testing NancyFx](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/making-my-first-nancyfx-test-pass.html)

Comment: @JefClaes - Thanks - your post is actually referenced in the original question.

Comment: I solved this by marking the view "Copy Always" AND disabling the custom root path provider.